# How to correctly set the value of placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've written the following quick program in tensorflow to print fibonacci numbers. Initial fib numbers are initialized as placeholders `x1` and `x2` However when I try to feed the value of the placeholders in `session.run` it results in the error :

`InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x2' with dtype int64 and shape [1]`

Can you help me understand and fix the problem with my code?

```
import tensorflow as tf
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
import numpy as np

ones = tf.ones((1,))

n = 10
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1], name='x1')
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1], name='x2')
temp = tf.Variable(ones, name='temp')

tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
fib_nums = [x1, x2]
for i in range(100):
  temp = x1 + x2
  x1 = x2
  x2 = temp
  fib_nums.append(temp)

series = tf.stack(fib_nums)
print(np.ones(1).astype(np.int64))
session.run(series, feed_dict={x1:np.ones(1).astype(np.int64), x2:np.ones(1).astype(np.int64)})
print(series.eval())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here. First, since you are reusing the Python names `x1` and `x2`, when you give them in the `feed_dict` they no longer refer to the placeholders, but to the last results of the loop. So you should change your code so the keys that you give in `feed_dict` are truly the placeholders. Second, you first call `session.run` with the `feed_dict`, which is correct, but then you call `series.eval()`, which is essentially the same as the previous line, only you are not providing the `feed_dict` in this case so it is not going to work. You do not really need to call `series.eval()`, you can just take the value returned by `session.run`. Your fixed program could look something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
import numpy as np

ones = tf.ones((1,))

n = 10
# Reserve these Python names for the placeholders
x1_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1], name='x1')
x2_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [1], name='x2')
temp = tf.Variable(ones, name='temp')

tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
# Use placeholders as initial values in the iterations
x1, x2 = x1_ph, x2_ph
fib_nums = [x1, x2]
for i in range(100):
  temp = x1 + x2
  x1 = x2
  x2 = temp
  fib_nums.append(temp)

series = tf.stack(fib_nums)
print(np.ones(1).astype(np.int64))
# You can just give lists as inputs and TensorFlow will convert their type
series_val = sess.run(series, feed_dict={x1_ph: [1], x2_ph: [1]})
print(series_val)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[[                   1]
 [                   1]
 [                   2]
 [                   3]
 [                   5]
 [                   8]
 [                  13]
 [                  21]
 [                  34]
 [                  55]
 [                  89]
 [                 144]
 [                 233]
 [                 377]
 [                 610]
 [                 987]
 [                1597]
 [                2584]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think another variation is this using [tf.identity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity).

```
y = tf.identity(x1)
y1 = tf.identity(x2)
fib_nums = [y, y1]
for i in range(100):
  temp = y + y1
  y = y1
  y1 = temp
  fib_nums.append(temp)
```

This placeholder modification issue is also discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9960)

And this is one more way to get the series.

```
def cond(i, x_next, x_prev):
    return x_next <= 100

def body( i, x_next, x_prev ):

    nextinseries = x_next + x_prev

    next = tf.Print(x_next, [x_next], message="Next is : ")
    prev = tf.Print(x_prev, [x_prev], message="Previous is : ")

    with tf.control_dependencies([nextinseries]):
        prev = tf.identity( next )


    return [i + 1, nextinseries , prev ]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


sess.run(tf.while_loop(cond, body, [1, 1, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `tf.placeholder` to a tensor and it will work

```
x1 = tf.ones(dtype=tf.int64, shape=1, name='x1') 
x2 = tf.ones(dtype=tf.int64, shape=1, name='x2')
```